# How to know the ancestor-classes of a given class in JavaScript/ES6

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

```
var A = class A {};
var B = class B extends A {};
var C = class C extends B {};
```

Given the code above assuming I only have access to class 'C', how can I know what are its ancestor classes? The correct answer of course is B then A, but how can my code tell me that?

Comment: Ok I found one way. But is there  any simpler way perhaps? (C.prototype . __proto__ .constructor.prototype.__proto__.constructor
  === A);

Comment: Bergi wrote:  "This question has been asked before ..." . The earlier existing question was titled "Get parent class name from child with ES6?"  My question was not about how to find the NAME of the parent-class, but how to find the parent-class itself, actually all ancestor-classes. Not their NAMES. I don't care at all about their names.  So while the answers to the earlier question might answer also my question, these are clearly not duplicate questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the prototype chain of `C.prototype` and get the prototype's `constructor` property.

```js
var A = class A {};
var B = class B extends A {};
var C = class C extends B {};

var proto = C.prototype;
while (proto !== Object.prototype) {
  console.log(proto.constructor.name, proto.constructor);
  proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
}
```